# How can I get rotation in the X and Y Axis in object mode?

Tags: modeling

When I try to rotate an object in object mode,
It rotates only in the Z axis.
This axis seems to be a constrained axis.

How can I get rotation in the X and Y Axis in object mode?

Thank you.

Comment: Press R and Shift Z, that will prevent movement on the Z axis and will allow you to rotate on X and Y

Comment: have you locked the rotations on the X and Y axis? Check it in the N panel

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> after entering rotation mode will bound the rotation to only the x and y axis.
In general, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+*axis letter* will bind the translation to all axes apart from the chosen axis.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried what you proposed but it doesn't seem to work. I checked it in the N panel and all the axis were unblocked.

Comment: could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Uri you have to press this key combination AFTER you enter your translation mode (e.g. press "r" to rotate)